# trouble accessing www folders - permission or ownership?

Tags: apache2, localhost

Trying to access a folder inside /var/www with:

```
cd layout
```

I get the following response:

```
bash: cd: layout: Permission denied
```

When I list the details, I get:

```
drwxrw---- 7 www-data www-data 4096 Apr  9 15:21 layout
```

I've not seen this www-data before - what is it and how do I correct it?

Edit (more info): I can access these files with root through nautilus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www-data` is the user apache uses for the website. This is set in the config file for apache.

```
$ grep wwww-data /etc/apache2
envvars:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
envvars:export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

The Apache user/group should only have read access to the files in the web root so keep them as they are.

You should create a new group (something like `www-admin`) that has write access to those files and then add yourself to that group instead.

```
usermod -a -G www andy
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding my user to the group and I get the message that it's already there: useradd: user 'andy' already exists

Comment: use it with `-a` option. like `usermod -a -G www yourusername` with www as group to get added to

Answer (score 1):

www-data is the user used by apache2 webserver. as normal user you cannot do anything there, as you have no rights (the last --- mean that every user that is not www-data or in the same group has no rights).

You need to access it as root.

So do `sudo su` to permanently be root (this session) or `sudo` in front of every command

EDIT: Damn, a few seconds too late. Other way works too

Comment: it's ok yours if fine too :D There are more ways to Rome...

Comment: That's fine, but I can't access the file via the browser: localhost/layout - I get 403 forbidden.

Comment: because it now belongs to root. Assign it back to www-data by using `chown www-data filename.html` on it or use the solution by Rinzwind, also fine one